# What happened to Chopper's hat after the time-skip?

Tags: one-piece

Before the time-skip Chopper always used to wear the pink hat with an X mark which was given to him by Hiriluk. But after the time-skip he doesn't wear the same hat. As we know, his hat was as precious to him as Luffy's straw hat is to him.
I don't think he would let anything happen to the hat, also I don't think he would abandon the only memory of Hiriluk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the SBS from vol 63 (chapter 616), The pink one (original) is under the blue one (new).

[image: chooper hat combo]